# Dispatcher.Invoke() throws TaskCanceledException in NUnit Tests

Tags: .net, nunit, dispatcher

I'm trying to abstract the `Dispatcher` from our view models by using an interface. I've created a mock implementation of this interface which looks like the following:

```
public class MockIDispatcher : IDispatcher, IDisposable
{
    public MockIDispatcher()
    {
        var dispatcherThread = new Thread(Dispatcher.Run) { IsBackground = true };
        dispatcherThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        dispatcherThread.Start();

        while ((Dispatcher = Dispatcher.FromThread(dispatcherThread)) == null) Thread.Yield();  // need to wait until the thread we created has started its dispatcher
    }

    internal Dispatcher Dispatcher { get; }

    /* ... more implementation here */
}
```

I've created a dummy NUnit test as shown below, but the call to `Dispatcher.Invoke()` is throwing a `TaskCanceledException`.

```
[Test]
public void TestPoc()
{
    var foo = new MockIDispatcher();
    foo.Dispatcher.Invoke(() =>
    {
        Debug.WriteLine("Hey there!");
    });
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this code working? I'd like to actually use a Dispatcher behind the scenes in order to more easily play with things like `SynchronizationContext`s and the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue seems to be with how I got the `Dispatcher` in the constructor. I changed the constructor as shown below, and that solved the problem. Looks like you may need to actually call `Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher` on the thread first. Calling `Dispatcher.Run()` is not enough.

```
public MockIDispatcher()
{
    using (var mre = new ManualResetEvent(false))
    {
        Dispatcher dispatcher = null;
        var dispatcherThread = new Thread(() =>
        {
            dispatcher = Dispatcher.CurrentDispatcher;
// ReSharper disable once AccessToDisposedClosure Not Possible because we are waiting inside the using loop
            mre.Set();
            try { Dispatcher.Run(); } catch {  /* swallow exceptions */ }
        }) { IsBackground = true };

        dispatcherThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        dispatcherThread.Start();

        mre.WaitOne();
        Dispatcher = dispatcher;
    }
}
```